# Discord JS - Splitting big message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to split a big message using Util.splitMessage() function, but it's not working correctly. What have I written wrong?

```
const chunks = [] = Util.splitMessage(list.toString(), { maxLength: 1000 });
        chunks.forEach(async chunk => {
            await message.channel.send(chunk);
        });
```

Comment: Remove `= []  `.

Comment: Now I get this error:
RangeError [SPLIT_MAX_LEN]: Chunk exceeds the max length and contains no split characters.
What does it mean? Isn't it supposed to split this message?

Comment: Try adding a `char` option as an empty space

Comment: It worked, thanks